# IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY while using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to execute some code on some parsed JSON using Retrofit, but I am getting an Illegal State Exception. Here is my Retrofit instance:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        CoinbaseProAPI coinbaseProAPI = retrofit.create(CoinbaseProAPI.class);
```

The Coinbase Pro API interface:

```
@GET("products/{productId}/candles")
    Call<ArrayList<HistoricRates>> getHistoricRates(@Header("CB-ACCESS-SIGN") String signature,
        @Header("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP") String timeStamp,
        @Path("productId") String productId,
        @Query("start") String intervalStart,
        @Query("end") String intervalEnd,
        @Query("granularity") int granularity
    );
```

The call request to the server (this is what's causing the error):

```
Call<ArrayList<HistoricRates>> call = coinbaseProAPI.getHistoricRates(signature, timeStamp, productId, intervalStart, intervalEnd, granularity);
            try {
                //this is being executed inside a for loop; requests are rate limited so consecutive 
                //iterations must wait
                if (i > 0) {
                    call.wait(1010);
                }
                //this is the line the debugger doesn't like:
                Response<ArrayList<HistoricRates>> response = call.execute();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Message eMsg = errorHandler.obtainMessage();
                    String e = R.string.error_header + response.toString();
                    eMsg.what = 2;
                    eMsg.obj = e;
                    errorHandler.sendMessage(eMsg);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<HistoricRates> candles = response.body();
                    int n = 0;
                    double[][] aCandles = new double[3][3];
                    for (HistoricRates historicRates : candles) {
                        aCandles[n][0] = historicRates.getOpen();
                        aCandles[n][1] = historicRates.getClose();
                        aCandles[n][2] = historicRates.getVolume();
                        n++;
                    }
                    selectedAsset.setCandles(aCandles);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Message eMsg = errorHandler.obtainMessage();
                eMsg.what = 2;
                eMsg.obj = e.getMessage();
                errorHandler.sendMessage(eMsg);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And finally the class object the JSON is being parsed into:

```
public class HistoricRates {
    private int time;
    private double low;
    private double high;
    private double open;
    private double close;
    private double volume;

    public double getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public double getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

So from what I gather from similar posts, Illegal State Exception occurs because the object I'm trying to pass to Gson is not of the correct type. But I don't understand how this could be, given that I'm using Retrofit; shouldn't the GsonConverterFactory take care of this for me? Also, even though I have this code enclosed within a try/catch block, it is not actually throwing an exception; it just fails silently. The only reason I even know about the Illegal State Exception is because of the Debug Console. How can I improve my error reporting or is there something else I'm not understanding?

EDIT TO ADD:
Tried Capps99's solution (with added accessor method included in HistoricRatesList so I can get an iterator to loop through the values) Here is what that looks like:

```
HistoricRatesList candles = response.body();
                    Iterator candleIterator = candles.getList().iterator();
                    int n = 0;
                    double[][] aCandles = new double[3][3];
                    while (candleIterator.hasNext()) {
                        HistoricRates historicRates = (HistoricRates) candleIterator.next();
                        aCandles[n][0] = historicRates.getOpen();
                        aCandles[n][1] = historicRates.getClose();
                        aCandles[n][2] = historicRates.getVolume();
                        n++;
                    }
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting an Illegal State Exception. At the request of another commenter, here is the expected JSON response from the server(apologies I should have included this to begin with):

```
[
     //these are all decimal values except for time; which is an integer value 
     //representing the UNIX epoch time
     [time, low, high, open, close, volume],
     [time, low, high, open, close, volume],
     ...
]
```

Perhaps the trouble is that the server appears to be returning the data in the form of a 2D array, which I don't have the experience to know how to parse properly.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Can you add an example of your api return json data ?

Comment: are you using the correct API?. response of /candles is nested JSONArray. If you see coinbase documentation ur expected response matches with "products/{productId}/stats"

Comment: retrofit is telling that you that response is Array, which is correct. However, the type of HistoricRates declared is a object

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create the following class to parse the list.

```
public class HistoricRatesList {
 List<HistoricRates> historicRates;
}
```

and then use like this.

```
@GET("products/{productId}/candles")
    Call<HistoricRatesList> getHistoricRates(@Header("CB-ACCESS-SIGN") String signature,
        @Header("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP") String timeStamp,
        @Path("productId") String productId,
        @Query("start") String intervalStart,
        @Query("end") String intervalEnd,
        @Query("granularity") int granularity
    );
```